# POST data to json using my-json-server through Angular

Tags: angular, rest

I am trying to perform two simple tasks. GET and POST with a free REST api i.e Jsonplaceholder using angular. I have a json `db.json` uploaded on my github account [here](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/test-json-server) which is very simple. It contains `id` and name of the book i.e. `title`

```
{
    "myitems": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Bike Servicing System"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Easy Base"
        }
    ],
    "profile": {
        "name": "typicode"
    }
}
```

I am using a free REST api service `JSONPlaceholder`. They call it a "Fake Online REST API for Testing and Prototyping". Anyways, my GET request works perfectly. Click [here](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/test-json-server/myitems/) to see GET response. But why I am unable to put some further data to that json using POST. Please see if there is something wrong with my code.

```
post(opost: Posts): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.post("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/tmtanzeel/test-json-server/myitems", opost);
}
```

Where `opost` is an object of type `Posts` which is a class.

```
export class Posts {
    id: number;
    title: string;
}
```

I am not getting any error. [Here](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/book-rest) I have put the entire angular project on github. And I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdLJNGZvlAA) youtube tutorial. Please help me.

Comment: Do you subscribe to your POST request?

Comment: @igor_c Yes I did.

`var opost = new Posts();
    opost.id=3;
    opost.title='Dove Tail';

    this._freeApiService.post(opost)
    .subscribe (
      data=> {
        this.objposts = data;
      }
    );`

Answer (score 2):

From the `JSONPlaceholder` docs:

> To be able to provide a free service to as many people as possible during this phase, the project comes with a few limits:
>
> - Changes are faked and aren't persisted (just like JSONPlaceholder)

POST requests don't persist anything to the server. This makes sense, as it would mean requiring file write access to a server you don't own.

If you want a quick, local JSON server, try the `json-server` package (the basis for `JSONPlaceholder`:

https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Ok. but then I'll have to run two servers simultaneously. One for `json-server` and the other for 'npm start'. This will be a little dicey when i deploy the app on heroku. Any solution to this ? please

Comment: You can use `concurrently` to run multiple commands in the same `npm` script. You also don't need to "run" an Angular server when deploying, unless you're using SSR. You simply deploy the production build as static files.